# How to delete rows before, after and when a certain event occurs?

Tags: r

How is it possible to drop observation days when the monitoring effort is not like 24 hours (n_hours)? Additionally also the entire observation day before and afterwards has to be deleted, when the monitoring effort is not like 24 hours. The definition off an entire observation day, is when the date variable are similar and share the same ID eg. row 4 and 5.

```
test <- data.frame(ID = as.factor(c('1', '1', '1', '1', 
                                    '1', '1', '2', '2',
                                    '2', '2')),
                   n_hours = as.factor(c('24', '24', '13', '24', 
                                                     '24', '24', '24', '21',
                                                     '24', '24')),
                   date = as.POSIXct(c('2020-03-31', '2020-04-01', 
                                       '2020-04-02', '2020-04-03', 
                                       '2020-04-03', '2020-04-04',
                                       '2020-04-02', '2020-04-03',
                                       '2020-04-04', '2020-04-05')))
```

Expected output

```
> test
  ID   n_hours     date
1  1     24     2020-03-31
2  1     24     2020-04-04
3  2     24     2020-04-05
```

I tried this already.

```
test$x<- 0 
test$x[c(sapply(which(test$n != 24), `+`, -1:1))] <- 1 
test <- test[test$x==0,]
```

In this case, the entire observation day e.g. Test [5,] is not removed.

```
> test[5,]
  ID n_hours       date
5  1      24 2020-04-03
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a custom function which deletes observations within +/- 1 day of `n_hours != 24`.

```
delete_rows <- function(hrs, date) {
  inds <- which(hrs != 24)
  !date %in% unique(c(date[inds] - 1, date[inds], date[inds] + 1))
}
```

and apply it for each `ID`.

```
library(dplyr)

test %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(date)) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(delete_rows(n_hours, date)) %>%
  ungroup

#  ID    n_hours date      
#  <fct> <fct>   <date>    
#1 1     24      2020-03-31
#2 1     24      2020-04-04
#3 2     24      2020-04-05
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If run your code I get: 
  ID    n_hours date      
  <fct> <fct>   <date>    
1 1     24      2020-03-30
2 1     24      2020-04-03
3 2     24      2020-04-04. Do you know why?

Comment: Why are you using `as.POSIXct` in your data when you have only dates in them? `as.POSIXct` uses local timezone, you can use `tz = 'UTC'` in `as.POSIXct` to use timezone as UTC (`as.POSIXct(c(....), tz = 'UTC')`) and try the answer again.

Comment: Yes, you were right as.POIXct caused the error. Thanks again.